# Jquery .next to img's inside anchor tags

Tags: jquery

I've searched and can't find a relevant topic. I want to .next through a bunch of images that have  around them here is what I have jquerycode:

```
    function swapImages(){
  var $active = $('#slideshow .active');
  var $next = $active.next().length > 0 ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow a img:first');
  $active.fadeOut(function(){
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
  });
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
  // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
  timerID = setInterval('swapImages()', 2000);

    $('#slideshow img').mouseover(function() {
        //$(this).addClass(' ');
        clearInterval(timerID);
    });
    $('#slideshow img').mouseout(function() {
        //$(this).addClass(' ');
        timerID = setInterval('swapImages()', 2000);
    });                              

});
```

And my html:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <a href=""><img src="images/image1.jpeg" class="active" /></a>
    <a href=""><img src="images/image2.jpeg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img src="images/image.jpeg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img src="images/image1BW.jpeg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img src="images/image2BW.jpeg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img src="images/imageBW.jpeg" /></a>
</div>
```

How do I select the next img with the anchor tags in place?

*edit: It seems to fail on the `$active.next().length > 0;` as it fails into the else statement http://simpleburn.com/ctv/ffinn/4th/

the img:first statement. I've tried setting `var $active = $('#slideshow a img.active');` to no avail.

***edit FINAL SOLUTION**

```
<script>
function swapImages(){
  var $active = $('div#slideshow .active');
  var $next = $active.next().length > 0 ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow  img:first');
  $active.fadeOut(function(){
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
  });

    //alert(next);
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
      // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
      timerID = setInterval('swapImages()', 2000);

    $('#slideshow img').bind({
        click: function(){
        window.location.href = '/shows/' + $j(this).attr('alt');
        },
        mouseenter: function(){
        //$(this).addClass(' ');
        clearInterval(timerID);
        }
    });
    $('#slideshow img').mouseout(function() {
        //$(this).addClass(' ');
        timerID = setInterval('swapImages()', 2000);
    });

});
```

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slideshow">
       <img src="images/image1.jpeg" alt="playerA" class="active"/>
       <img src="images/image2.jpeg" alt="playerB" />
       <img src="images/image.jpeg" alt="playerC" />
       <img src="images/image1BW.jpeg" alt="playerD" />
       <img src="images/image2BW.jpeg" alt="playerE" />
       <img src="images/imageBW.jpeg" alt="playerF" />
    </div>
```

Comment: @ezmilhouse woops, missed my code tag.

Comment: You can select the parent of the img tag then use next then select the img tag inside.

Comment: Not on topic, but I think it's better to use `.hover()` instead of `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()`, as that's essentially what `.hover()` does for you, plus it will save you on re-querying the DOM for `$("#slideshow img")`.

Comment: Yeah I thought .hover would work, but it wouldn't resume the cycle once the mouse moved off the image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that?

```
var next = $('#slideshow img').not('.active').attr('src');
alert(next);
```

don't know what you mean bei anchor tag in place?

#### UPDATE: REPLACING a tags (see comments, just brainstorming)

Markup:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="images/image1.jpeg" class="active" alt="index-images-1.html" />
    ...
```

jQuery:

```
$( '#slideshow img' ).live('click', function(){

   // if clicked ...
   // maybe you could give your images a 'alt' attr
   // that help to identify a link destination
   var hint = $(this).attr('alt');

   // then link out ...
   window.location.href = 'http://foo.com/' + hint;

})
```

Comment: It just means that if I remove the anchor tags the script works.

Comment: so why not removing the anchor tags and handling the link via bind/live (click event)?

Comment: another idea - what happens if you add the .active to the 'a' tags instead of the img tags?

Comment: Yeah it sounds like that is the way to do this. Any hints on doing that with different links?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did a hybrid of my original code, and the bind idea you gave me.

Comment: btw - you can make it a one-liner for all cases: window.location.href = '/shows/' + $(this).attr('alt') - 'this' means he always takes the alt attr of the current element in loop

Comment: @ezmilhouse Thanks, and edited final to reflect that. Thanks again for your help!!